# Убрать отступы matplotlib графика в pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, matplotlib

Сделал приложение на *Python* + *PyQt5* и мне понадобилось вставить в него график из `mpl`. Но сделав это получил нежелательные отступы (пометил синим). Они плохо влияют на визуальную составляющую + я так понимаю из-за них возникает проблема неравномерного растягивания графика при увеличении окна.

Я хочу что бы площадь выделенную в сетке занимали только непосредственно оси и построенный график, а сейчас большую часть при растягивании и занимают отступы.

Собственно как можно решить эти 2 проблемы.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvas
 
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
 
#from matplotlib import rcParams
 
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
 
 
 
import random
 
#rcParams['font.family'] = "Segoe UI"
#rcParams['font.sans-serif'] = ['Tahoma']
#rcParams["figure.frameon"] = False
#rcParams["axes.grid"] = True
 
#
app = QApplication([])
#
mainWindow = QMainWindow()
mainWindow.resize(960, 270)
#
centralwidget = QWidget(mainWindow)
gridLayout = QGridLayout(centralwidget)
#
mainWindow.setCentralWidget(centralwidget)
#
groupBox_0 = QGroupBox("Serial", centralwidget)
gridLayout.addWidget(groupBox_0, 0, 0, 1, 1)
groupBox_0.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
gridLayout_0 = QGridLayout(groupBox_0)
 
groupBox_0.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Fixed, QSizePolicy.Fixed)
 
groupBox_1 = QGroupBox("Device", centralwidget)
gridLayout.addWidget(groupBox_1, 1, 0, 1, 1)
groupBox_1.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
gridLayout_1 = QGridLayout(groupBox_1)
 
groupBox_2 = QGroupBox("Action", centralwidget)
gridLayout.addWidget(groupBox_2, 2, 0, 1, 1)
groupBox_2.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
gridLayout_2 = QGridLayout(groupBox_2)
#
spinBox_0 = QSpinBox(groupBox_1)
gridLayout_1.addWidget(spinBox_0, 2, 0, 1, 1)
#
lineEdit_0 = QLineEdit("1A86:7523", groupBox_0)
gridLayout_0.addWidget(lineEdit_0, 0, 0, 1, 1)
#lineEdit_0.setMinimumSize(60, 0)
lineEdit_0.setMaximumSize(60, 20)
lineEdit_0.setEnabled(False)
#
comboBox_0 = QComboBox(groupBox_0)
gridLayout_0.addWidget(comboBox_0, 1, 0, 1, 1)
#
pushButton_0 = QPushButton("Auto connect", groupBox_0)
gridLayout_0.addWidget(pushButton_0, 0, 1, 1, 1)
#pushButton_0.setEnabled(False)
 
pushButton_1 = QPushButton("Main connect", groupBox_0)
gridLayout_0.addWidget(pushButton_1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
#pushButton_1.setEnabled(False)
 
pushButton_2 = QPushButton("Hold sample", groupBox_1)
gridLayout_1.addWidget(pushButton_2, 0, 0, 1, 2)
#pushButton_2.setEnabled(False)
 
pushButton_3 = QPushButton("Drop sample", groupBox_1)
gridLayout_1.addWidget(pushButton_3, 1, 0, 1, 2)
#pushButton_3.setEnabled(False)
 
pushButton_4 = QPushButton("Set", groupBox_1)
gridLayout_1.addWidget(pushButton_4, 2, 1, 1, 1)
#pushButton_4.setEnabled(False)
 
pushButton_5 = QPushButton("Move sample ▲", groupBox_1)
gridLayout_1.addWidget(pushButton_5, 3, 0, 1, 2)
#pushButton_5.setEnabled(False)
 
pushButton_6 = QPushButton("Move sample ▼", groupBox_1)
gridLayout_1.addWidget(pushButton_6, 4, 0, 1, 2)
#pushButton_6.setEnabled(False)
 
pushButton_7 = QPushButton("Spectral analisys", groupBox_2)
gridLayout_2.addWidget(pushButton_7, 0, 0, 1, 1)
#pushButton_7.setEnabled(False)
 
pushButton_8 = QPushButton("Machine analisys", groupBox_2)
gridLayout_2.addWidget(pushButton_8, 1, 0, 1, 1)
#pushButton_8.setEnabled(False)
 
figure = Figure(facecolor="None")
 
data = [random.random() for i in range(2000)]
 
canvas = FigureCanvas(figure)
gridLayout.addWidget(canvas, 0, 1, 3, 1)
ax = canvas.figure.add_subplot(111, facecolor="None")
 
ax.plot(data, 'r-')
 
#canvas.setStyleSheet("background-color:transparent;")
 
canvas.draw()
 
#
mainWindow.show()
#
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте добавить:

```
margins = {                                            
    "left"   : 0.040,
    "bottom" : 0.060,
    "right"  : 0.990,
    "top"    : 0.990   
}

figure.subplots_adjust(**margins)
```

---

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
import random


app = QApplication([])

mainWindow = QMainWindow()
mainWindow.resize(960, 270)

centralwidget = QWidget(mainWindow)
gridLayout = QGridLayout(centralwidget)

mainWindow.setCentralWidget(centralwidget)

groupBox_0 = QGroupBox("Serial", centralwidget)
gridLayout.addWidget(groupBox_0, 0, 0, 1, 1)
groupBox_0.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
gridLayout_0 = QGridLayout(groupBox_0)

groupBox_0.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Fixed, QSizePolicy.Fixed)

groupBox_1 = QGroupBox("Device", centralwidget)
gridLayout.addWidget(groupBox_1, 1, 0, 1, 1)
groupBox_1.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
gridLayout_1 = QGridLayout(groupBox_1)

groupBox_2 = QGroupBox("Action", centralwidget)
gridLayout.addWidget(groupBox_2, 2, 0, 1, 1)
groupBox_2.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
gridLayout_2 = QGridLayout(groupBox_2)

spinBox_0 = QSpinBox(groupBox_1)
gridLayout_1.addWidget(spinBox_0, 2, 0, 1, 1)

lineEdit_0 = QLineEdit("1A86:7523", groupBox_0)
gridLayout_0.addWidget(lineEdit_0, 0, 0, 1, 1)
#lineEdit_0.setMinimumSize(60, 0)
lineEdit_0.setMaximumSize(60, 20)
lineEdit_0.setEnabled(False)

comboBox_0 = QComboBox(groupBox_0)
gridLayout_0.addWidget(comboBox_0, 1, 0, 1, 1)

pushButton_0 = QPushButton("Auto connect", groupBox_0)
gridLayout_0.addWidget(pushButton_0, 0, 1, 1, 1)
#pushButton_0.setEnabled(False)

pushButton_1 = QPushButton("Main connect", groupBox_0)
gridLayout_0.addWidget(pushButton_1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
#pushButton_1.setEnabled(False)

pushButton_2 = QPushButton("Hold sample", groupBox_1)
gridLayout_1.addWidget(pushButton_2, 0, 0, 1, 2)
#pushButton_2.setEnabled(False)

pushButton_3 = QPushButton("Drop sample", groupBox_1)
gridLayout_1.addWidget(pushButton_3, 1, 0, 1, 2)
#pushButton_3.setEnabled(False)

pushButton_4 = QPushButton("Set", groupBox_1)
gridLayout_1.addWidget(pushButton_4, 2, 1, 1, 1)
#pushButton_4.setEnabled(False)

pushButton_5 = QPushButton("Move sample ▲", groupBox_1)
gridLayout_1.addWidget(pushButton_5, 3, 0, 1, 2)
#pushButton_5.setEnabled(False)

pushButton_6 = QPushButton("Move sample ▼", groupBox_1)
gridLayout_1.addWidget(pushButton_6, 4, 0, 1, 2)
#pushButton_6.setEnabled(False)

pushButton_7 = QPushButton("Spectral analisys", groupBox_2)
gridLayout_2.addWidget(pushButton_7, 0, 0, 1, 1)
#pushButton_7.setEnabled(False)

pushButton_8 = QPushButton("Machine analisys", groupBox_2)
gridLayout_2.addWidget(pushButton_8, 1, 0, 1, 1)
#pushButton_8.setEnabled(False)

margins = {                                            # <<<-----<
    "left"   : 0.040,
    "bottom" : 0.060,
    "right"  : 0.990,
    "top"    : 0.990   
}

figure = Figure(facecolor="None")
figure.subplots_adjust(**margins)                      # <<<-----<

data = [random.random() for i in range(2000)]

canvas = FigureCanvas(figure)
gridLayout.addWidget(canvas, 0, 1, 3, 1)

ax = canvas.figure.add_subplot(111, facecolor="None")
ax.plot(data, 'r-')

canvas.draw()

mainWindow.show()
app.exec_()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо! Вроде нечто похожее побывал но не заработало, а ваш код делает именно то что нужно. Проблема решена